# Validar email em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde,

Estou com uma duvida num exercício que tenho de resolver e queria vos pedir que me ajudassem:

Como faço uma função em JavaScript que toma como argumento uma string e verifica se um email é valido, ou seja, se conter @ é um email. E a função retorna um booleano. 
Obrigada

Comment: Voce pode usar expressoes regulares para verificar se a string recebida 'e um email valido. Da uma olhada nesse link: [RegexOne](http://regexone.com/) ele vai te dar uma boa base.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode validar usando esta função:

```
function IsEmail(email){
    var exclude=/[^@-.w]|^[_@.-]|[._-]{2}|[@.]{2}|(@)[^@]*1/;
    var check=/@[w-]+./;
    var checkend=/.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/;
    if(((email.search(exclude) != -1)||(email.search(check)) == -1)||(email.search(checkend) == -1)){return false;}
    else {return true;}
}
```

fonte: http://codigofonte.uol.com.br/codigos/validacao-completa-de-email-com-javascript-e-expressao-regular

Comment: Muito Obrigada!

Comment: Para quem estiver tentando consultar o link da fonte, o link atual é [este](https://codigofonte.com.br/codigos/validacao-completa-de-email-com-javascript-e-expressao-regular).

Comment: parece que a expressão regular que a variável  exclude está recebendo não é mais válida